# how to replace image on click, Knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'd appriciate if anyone could help =)
i want my image to change when i click on it

.html file:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.markCompleted"><img class = "check" src = 'bee-icon-gray.jpg' width = '25px' height = '23px'/></a>
```

.js file

```
    function AppViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);

      self.markCompleted = function(task) {
                task.status('completed');
                }
}
```

So i'd like to replace `bee-icon-gray.jpg` image with `bee-icon-colored.jpg` when i click on it, also it would be just perfect if i could toggle the images each time i click!
i'd be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','newimagesrc');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

In a normal web page, indeed using the jquery selector would be best, but because you are building a SPA with knockout, mixing jquery selects in your view model is a no-no.

So, end response:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.markCompleted"><img class = "check" data-bind='attr: {src: imageSrc}' width = '25px' height = '23px'/></a>
```

and in your view model:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.imageSrc = 'initialImage';
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.markCompleted = function(task) {
        task.status('completed');
        self.imageSrc('newImage');
    }
}
```